# Not able to add multiple column against same ID in table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables x and y, x have the ID and many other columns, however y only have the ID similar as x table and then this ID is mapped to Many values

My Insert statement looks like this

```
INSERT INTO `table`
(`id`,
`other_name`)
VALUES
(select id from another_table where name = 'something'`,
('WALLETAB',
'SBTRADER',
'SBTRDACKING'));
```

expected result

```
1 | WALLETAB
1 | SBTRADER
1 | SBTRDACKING
```

I take ID from another table which already have data and  this another table some different data associated with this table

Comment: you can use `limit 1` on the `select`.

Comment: Syntactic nonsense..please add sample data as text to the question and full error message and try to be consistent - talking of x and y table then publishing code which has nether does not aid clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fetch `id` from another table to be used in `insert` statement by using `limit 1`, something like:

```
select id from another_table where name = 'something' limit 1
```

However, to insert all 3 rows you will need a multiple insert in a single statement.

```
insert into `table` values
  ((select id from another_table where name = 'something' limit 1), 'WALLETAB'),
  ((select id from another_table where name = 'something' limit 1), 'SBTRADER'),
  ((select id from another_table where name = 'something' limit 1), 'SBTRDACKING');
```

See fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gYvrxdsDxVQPkZM2o8YRT1/1

It feels a lot of duplication. You can simplify it by either using variable or CTE. The following query utilizes CTE which only usable on [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) 8+:

```
insert into `table` (id, other_name)
with
 other_id as (
   select id from another_table where name = 'something'),
 merged as (
   select id, other_name from other_id join 
   (select 'WALLETAB' as other_name
      union select 'SBTRADER'
      union select 'SBTRDACKING')
    as other_temp)
select * from merged;
```

The CTE above fetch the `id` on `other_id`. The `union`-`select` pairs is then used to create 3 rows containing `'WALLETAB'`, `'SBTRADER'`, and `'SBTRDACKING'` respectively. Then both of them joined to get 3 rows with varying value on `other_name` but has `id` as `1`.

See fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xgQta17bGphHAB81N2FNwX/1